# How To take union and intersaction of two strings in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, union, intersection

i have a requirement like taking UNION and INTERSECTION at character level in objective c.

"StringA" , "StringB"

Results in case of (UNION) for above string : "StringAB"
Results in case of (Intersection) for above string : "String"

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this a set union or what? What would the union of "StringA" and "Strong" be?

Comment: What is union of ""StringAB", ""StringB" ?

Comment: UNION: "StringAB" & Intersection:"String" its just like maths AUB and A∩B.

Comment: What about "StringB" and "ingB"?

Comment: UMAR, you didn't answer Chuck's question.  Is the union "StringAStrong", "StriongA", "StringStrongA", what??

Comment: This sounds like homework to me.

Comment: Its not a home work but a logical question inwhich i am stuck :( as i explained There is a string 1: "StringA"  and second "StringB" i need intersection of both strings, Intersection result would be "String" that is the common character part of it nothing else, where as, Union of both would be combined all characters and write duplicate characters only once hence "StringAB" would be result.

Comment: Obviously, you still have not explained yourself well enough.  What is the answer to Chuck's question?  Then, answer what would be the union of "Strong" and "StringA"...

Comment: It looks like you want to operate on the sets of characters in each string. Does the order of the characters in the inputs or output matter? Are duplicate letters ignored or treated separately?

Comment: In case of union duplicate letters will be used only once in resultant string by comparing both strings. in case of intersection only common characters from both strings will be displayed in resultant string.

Comment: Don't you then just end up with the alphabet for the union?  I mean, your "StringAB" result could just as well be "ABginrSt", and the "union" is easily computed by concatenating the strings, sorting the characters, and deleting the dupes.

Comment: (I don't believe you've thought this out very well at all.)

Comment: Yes your feedback is very interesting :)

Comment: Thank you very much "hot licks" you are the person who understood my requirement and provided me solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the help of stackoverflow member finally i got solution to these problems

Intersection:

```
NSMutableSet *set1 = [NSMutableSet setWithArray: array1];
NSSet *set2 = [NSSet setWithArray: array2];
[set1 intersectSet: set2];
NSArray *resultArray = [set1 allObjects];
```

UNION:
Concatinate two strings and remove duplicating characters from that string and finally you will get the UNION :)

```
SString *input = @"addbcddaa";
NSMutableSet *seenCharacters = [NSMutableSet set];
NSMutableString *result = [NSMutableString string];
[input enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, input.length) options:NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
    if (![seenCharacters containsObject:substring]) {
        [seenCharacters addObject:substring];
        [result appendString:substring];
    }
}];
NSLog(@"String with duplicate characters removed: %@", result);
NSLog(@"Sorted characters in input: %@", [seenCharacters.allObjects sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)]);
```

Thank you!